Building signed APK with cmake and QT6
I build a .apk package using Qt 6.7.1 following the link
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-building-projects-from-commandline.html
Particularlly to generate the project I used the command
c:\Qt\6.7.1\android_arm64_v8a\bin\qt-cmake -DANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\android\sdk -DANDROID_NDK_ROOT=D:\android\sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 -S .. -B . -G "MinGW Makefiles"

Following
cmake --build .

My JAVA_HOME is "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17"
I would like to know how to signed this apk through command line. I know how to signed using QtCreator, however I am in difficult to build the apk after updating to Qt6
I tried the link https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/cmake-variable-qt-android-sign-apk.html
My build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qtAndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion
    ndkVersion androidNdkVersion

    namespace "com.comm5.visaomobile"
    // Extract native libraries from the APK
    packagingOptions.jniLibs.useLegacyPackaging true

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qtAndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['resources']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion qtMinSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion qtTargetSdkVersion
        ndk.abiFilters = qtTargetAbiList.split(",")
    }
}

My AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="****.***.***" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="28" android:versionName="1.28">
    <!-- %%INSERT_PERMISSIONS -->
    <!-- %%INSERT_FEATURES -->
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"/>
    <application android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtApplication" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:label="Visao Mobile" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:allowBackup="true" android:fullBackupOnly="false" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <activity android:name="org.qtproject.qt.android.bindings.QtActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|uiMode|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection|locale|fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|mcc|mnc|density" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:screenOrientation="unspecified" android:exported="true" android:label="">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_LIB_NAME%% --"/>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.arguments" android:value="-- %%INSERT_APP_ARGUMENTS%% --"/>
    </activity>

    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.qtprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/qtprovider_paths"/>
    </provider>

    <service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
</manifest>


At last, my gradle-wrapper.properties
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-bin.zip


I tried to
c:\Qt\6.7.1\android_arm64_v8a\bin\qt-cmake -DANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\android\sdk -DANDROID_NDK_ROOT=D:\android\sdk\ndk\26.1.10909125 -S .. -B . -G "MinGW Makefiles"   -DQT_ANDROID_BUILD_ALL_ABIS=True -DQT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH=..\keystore\key.keystore -DQT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS=*** -DQT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_PASS=***

and also tried to set QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PATH, QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS and QT_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_KEY_PAS as evironment Windows variables but it did not work
